# Why isn't the concat() working in react/hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const onClick = () => {
    const octokit = new Octokit({
      headers: {
        accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
        authorization: `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`,
      },
    });
    const response = octokit.request(`GET /orgs/{org}/repos`, {
      org: "octokit",
      type: "public",
    });
    response //
      .then((res) =>
        res.data.map((data) => {
          const info = user.concat({
            name: data.full_name,
            id: data.id,
            avatar: data.owner.avatar_url,
          });
          setUser(info);
          console.log(user);
        })
      );
  };
```

Why is it only the last value written as above?

Below is the result when pressed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51uHw.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "set" operation is asynchronous, so each iteration of `map()` is seeing the same value of `user` and queueing its own call to `setUser`.  When the thread is available, all of the asynchronous `setUser` operations are performed, and each one concats one element to an empty array.  So whichever is performed last will be the remaining value of `user`.

If `res.data` contains an array that should be mapped to the `user` value, perform the mapping first and then set the complete result.  Perhaps something like this:

```
const info = res.data.map((data) => ({
    name: data.full_name,
    id: data.id,
    avatar: data.owner.avatar_url,
}));
setUser(info);
```

Semantically you shouldn't be using `map` like a "loop" the way you are anyway.  `map` is for projecting a collection into another collection of the same length, not for iterating over elements and performing an operation.

While we're talking semantics, variable names like "user" imply only a single instance where yours is an array.  And variable names like "info" imply nothing useful at all.  Some quick renaming makes the code much more clear:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

// later...
const updatedUsers = res.data.map(u => ({
    name: u.full_name,
    id: u.id,
    avatar: u.owner.avatar_url,
}));
setUsers(updatedUsers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved the problem.